# Can I use application/json content type in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wp-admin, admin, json

I was using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and it was working all ok then I changed the content type to `application/json` and it is returning a *400 Bad Request* error.

Is it that WordPress dosn't support `application/json` or something else? And if WordPress dosn't support it is there any way to enable it?

**This is my code:**

```
const search = document.querySelector('input.search')
const posts = document.querySelector('section.posts')

search.addEventListener('input', () => {

    const data = {
        action: 'data_fetch',
        keyword: `${search.value}`
    }

    const request = fetch('./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
    })

    request.then(response => response.text())
    request.then(response => posts.innerHTML = response)
    request.catch(console.error)
    
})
```

Before I changed it to `application/json` the data was like this `action=data_fetch&keyword=${search.value}` and it was working.

Comment: You don't need to, abandon the old `admin-ajax.php` API and instead use the more modern and superior REST API which uses JSON. https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Comment: Oh thanks! Will read about it!